# How do I modify a dependent function in r?

Tags: r, function, dependencies

I am using the function clhs, which calls on the function `cor`. I would like to change the default settings that `clhs` uses for `cor`.

`clhs` has the following default settings for `cor`

```
cor(data_continuous, use = "complete.obs")
```

I want to change `cor to (data.continuous, use="all.obs")` while using `clhs`.

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Comment: I assume that is in some other package that you didn't mention. all the code is provided to you, you can just make a new function, eg my_clhs, in which you only change that single line. There may be a way to pass that argument directly to clhs, but this way is easy, too (provided that clhs doesn't depend on other functions in the package, then you'd have to tweak it a little)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i'm guessing you were looking specifically at the `clhs.data.frame` function from the `clhs` package. Technically, you can change the innards of functions. Here's how to make your requested change. Just to make sure you are modifying the correct line, look at

```
body(clhs.data.frame)[[10]]
```

For me at least, that returned the call to `cor()`. You can change that with

```
body(clhs.data.frame)[[10]] <- quote(cor_mat <- cor(data.continuous, use="all.obs"))
```

Then you should be able to use that function as before. But be forewarned that changing how the inside of of a function behaves could cause big problems for other functions that depend on a certain behavior.

A better idea would be to create a copy of the function with a different name that you can explicitly call when you need so it doesn't interfere with anything else.

To show how this works, I'll create a simple example (because the `clhs.data.frame` function is very big`). Let's say the`ff` function is defined by someone else and we need to use it on our data

```
ff<-function(x) {
    y <- x+2
    y <- head(y,-1)
    z <- sum(y)
    return( z/2 )
}


ff(c(1,2,3,4,5))     #9
ff(c(1,NA,3,4,5))    #NA
```

Oh no. Passing an `NA` in the vector causes a problem. If only they had specified `na.rm=T` in the `sum` it would work. So why not change it

```
body(ff)[[4]]<-quote(z<-sum(y, na.rm=T))
ff(c(1,NA,3,4,5))    #7
```

Notice that when you call `body(ff)` you actually see the body of the function. This is actually a list that you can manipulate. Each index corresponds to a command or block of code and `body(ff)[[4]]` is the line of code that has the `sum` call. So we just want to swap out that line for our own version (being careful to escape our expression so that it's not evaluated right away). Now when we run the function again, we get the "improved" behavior.

I just wanted to let you know it is possible to change functions like this (which makes R pretty cool) but it also may potentially cause many side effects so you're safer not doing it this way.